# If a non zero vector multiplied by a matrix is 0, then the determinant of the matrix is 0

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a question with regards to a 3x3 matrix, in a proof, this claim is made:

If, 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
 a & b & c
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11}       & x_{12} & x_{13}  \\
    x_{21}       & x_{22} & x_{23} \\
    x_{d1}       & x_{d2} & x_{d3}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then,
$$det(\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11}       & x_{12} & x_{13}  \\
    x_{21}       & x_{22} & x_{23} \\
    x_{d1}       & x_{d2} & x_{d3}
\end{bmatrix}) = 0$$

here $\begin{bmatrix}
 a & b & c
\end{bmatrix} $ is non zero 
I would like to know why this is true. Does this theorem exist and does it have a name?

Comment: You might like to add "non-zero".  The zero vector multiplied by any matric will be zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is another information that is missing. I think in this case, at least one of $a,b$, or $c$ is non-zero. In that case, the system has a non-trivial solution. Hence the matrix must be singular.

Singular matrices have zero determinant.

Comment: Ah, I see, is my reasoning correct:

It can be solved by row reduction, so as long as one of a, b, c is 0. then one of the starting terms on the diagonal has to be 0. Which makes the determinant 0.

Comment: Nope. The matrix system can be solved by row reduction after a transpose. Otherwise, you want to do column reduction. Note that there are singular matrices with all entries being non-zero. Also, there are matrices with every diagonal entries being zeros and yet they are non-singular.

Comment: Yes, of course, it has to be column reduction! I do see now that there are singular matrices with all entries being non-zero and there are matrices with every diagonal entries being zeros and yet they are non-singular. For the column reduced form, if a single diagonal entry is 0, then the matrix is singular? Thank you for clearing that misconception! I'll have to work on clearing a lot of other ones too!

Comment: The reduced form is a triangular matrix and the determinant of a triangular matrix is the product of the diagonals. Hence if one of them is zero, it is singular.